# What does it mean to uncheck a css property from the developer console? How can I emulate this using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

What is exactly happening when I check-uncheck the CSS property in developer console as shown (marked in red)

[image]

I want exactly the same behavior that occurs when I uncheck `height` in the developer console (currently set as height: auto !important). I tried

```
element.style.height = "unset"
```

but this does not work. How could I have the same behavior using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

> What is exactly happening when I check-uncheck the CSS property in developer console as shown

It removes the rule while storing enough data about it that it can be added in again easily.

That causes an other rule for the property from another source (such as another rule-set in the pages stylesheet, the browser's default stylesheet, or an inherited value) to apply instead.

> How could I have the same behavior using javascript?

With difficulty.

You'd need to identify the source of the rule which could be inline style (accessed via the `style` property on the DOM element) or a rule-set (accessed via the [CSSOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model)).

Then you'd need to record the current location and value so you could reapply it later.

Then you would have to remove the value.

---

> ```
> element.style.height = "unset"
> ```
>
> but this does not work.

There are two problems with this:

- It doesn't take into account `!important` rules
- `unset` resets the value to either the initial or inherited value, it doesn't remove a rule and let the previously cascaded rule apply.

Comment: "With difficulty." At best. On some stylesheets the browser prevents you from accessing the rules at all. Don't know when exactly, just saying that on top of the difficulty, it's also unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

Off topic: Not an aswer to your question, but a solution to you problem.

[Quentin gave a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63410537/6567275) on how it is difficult to do what you're asking for, and I added a comment to his answer that on top of that, the browser may completely prevent you from doing so, so let's approach the underlying problem and not your attempt at solving it:

You're trying to disable `.accountBox { height: auto!important; }` because it is overwriting your inline defined `height: 409px`, right?

But it has become a [specifity war](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+important+wars). Like who has the last say about what the value will be.

Since you can't make an inline style any more specific, you need to overrule the important height on the `.accountBox` by making your inline height important as well:
*(and the same for `margin-bottom` if I'm correct)*

```
element.style.setProperty("height", "409px", "important");
element.style.setProperty("margin-bottom", "24px", "important");
```

or

```
<div class="accountBox" style="height: 409px!important; margin-bottom: 24px!important;">
```

Answer (score -2):

You can set a default value like:

```
element.style.height = "auto"
```

Comment: That's just changing it to a new value, it wouldn't remove the existing value and let another existing rule take its place.